How to scan a subnet with nmap opening subprocesses and display the output simultaneously?
I'm trying to maintain a LIST of IP addresses from the subnet given by user in text box and then nmap them simultaneously using max 50 threads and displaying result of each IP as soon as it completes. The code is throwing multiple erros, especially in the subprocess part:-
# Scanning subnet of IP Addresses using NMAP

def Scan_IP(self):
    num_threads = 50
    global user_IP, i, scanout_q
    scanin_q = queue.Queue()
    scanout_q = queue.Queue()

    text = str(self.textbox.text().strip())

    # Fetching IP/ Subnet
    if text.upper().isupper() is False:
        try:
            def scan(i, q):
                while True:
                    # get an IP item from queue
                    IP = q.get()
                    
                    # scan nw devices
                    arg = f'nmap, -Pn, --open, -T5, {str(IP)}'
                    p4 = subprocess.Popen(arg, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding="utf-8", shell=True)

                    p5 = subprocess.Popen(
                        ["awk", "/scan report/; /STATE/; /tcp/; /type:/; Running/; /details:/; /Service Info:/"],
                        stdin=p4.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding="utf-8", shell = True)

                    output = p5.stdout.communicate()

                    # But do not wait till nmap finish, start displaying output immediately #
                    while True:
                        output = output.stderr.read()

                        if output == '':
                            pass
                        else:
                            sys.scanout_q.write(output)
                            sys.scanout_q.put(output)

                            sys.scanout_q.flush()

                    q.task_done()

            # start thread pool
            for i in range(num_threads):
                worker = Thread(target=scan, args=(i, scanin_q))
                worker.setDaemon(True)
                worker.start()

            # entering it into queue/ fill queue
            IP_List = []
            for IP in IPv4Network(text):
                scanin_q.put(IP)
                IP_List.append(IP)

            # queue management: wait until worker threads are done to exit
            scanin_q.join()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    else:
        errorMsg = '\nInvalid IP Address/ Subnet; Try again!'
        print(errorMsg)

Errors:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs
File "E:\PyCodes\NMAP.py", line 218, in scan output = p5.stdout.communicate()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'communicate'

What are the multiple errors it's throwing?

Anyway, you'll have a better time if you refactor your code into smaller parts you can develop and test in isolation: I'd refactor the function that calls nmap out into something you can just call without queues, threads, and (I guess) a GUI involved.

Edit the error into the question, don't post multiple comments.

Anyway, there you have it: p5.stdout is a stream, it doesn't have .communicate(). The process object, p5, does.

It is better to run single instance of nmap with multiple targets to scan.
nmap options which may be usefull (see man nmap):
-iL <inputfilename> target list
-oG - output to stdout in grepable format
